# Unity c# Array vs Static List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity game and I'm trying to write some idiomatic c# code.

What's the preferable way to write a collection of objects whose size will never change?

`static List<int> myList = new List<int>(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });`

or

`myList[int]= new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };`

Comment: Is you question about static or about arrays vs lists.  If the size is never changing might as well use an array.  If this list pertains to all of the object it resides within use static

Comment: How are you going to be using your collection?

Comment: I feel like you might not understand what `static` does

Comment: I used static because the array would never be mutated.  I expect the compiler to treat it a bit differently than if I was creating an array with dynamic size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters: arrays, the `static` keyword, and `List` are 3 separate things; this makes your question title a bit odd.  To answer the question asked in the body, ("*What's the preferable way to write a collection of objects whose size will never change?*") use an array but use the correct syntax: `int myList[] = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };`

If the size isn't changing, `List` is overkill.

Finally, whether or not it's `static` depends on what you want to use it for and shouldn't have anything to do with whether it's a `List` or array.